1U rack server that can hold a RTX 4080
Do you know of any 1 or 2 units rack server into which I can install a normal desktop PCIe RTX 4080 graphics card?

Do you plan to dismantle the RTX 4080's cooler and provide your own cooling? I don't think there is an RTX 4080 on the market that is narrow enough to fit in 1U. You definitely need 2U to fit a "normal desktop PCIe RTX 4080". I would still be worried about cooling one with the default cooler in 2U, it will be tight fit and might need a vent right over the GPU.

No I would rather us it "as is". But I can go with 2 units as well.

What you want is a vertical PCIe slot, like in this RackChoice Chassis, and a 16x PCIe extension cable.
If you want a pre-built computer, Stealth makes some: SR-2500
